# Django: Bulk Update Based on Calculation

Tags: django, orm, sql-update

I have a Django app that shows photos users can vote on. To make things simpler, I've denormalized the data so that the photo object has `current_rating` and `current_rank` fields. I want to update the `current_rank` field on all objects whenever a new vote is cast, but I'm not sure how to avoid doing that in a loop. How can I do:

```
i = 1
for p in Photo.objects.order_by("-current_rating"):
    p.current_rank = i
    p.save()
    i += 1
```

as one update operation in the ORM?

Answer (score 7):

I think what you mean is one transaction in the transaction manager, rather than one transaction per iteration.

I believe the loop construct is fine, but what you need to do is control the transaction manager.

First, you need to use the Django transaction manager, which you can read about here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/transactions/

You will need to add this line to your middleware_classes in settings.py

```
'django.middleware.transaction.TransactionMiddleware',
```

Then you will need to import transaction wherever your above function resides;

```
from django.db import transaction
```

Put your loop in a function and add a decorator, like so:

```
@transaction.commit_on_success
def my_function():
    i = 1
    for p in Photo.objects.order_by("-current_rating"):
        p.current_rank = i
        p.save()
    i += 1
```

Now when that function is called it will only have one transaction, rather then N. If it fails, the transaction rollsback.

You can also use commit_manually. See the docs above for more detail.

Comment: Definitely good stuff and I will, but I was actually looking to see if there was a way to do it as a bulk update with an F() object like https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#filters-can-reference-fields-on-the-model

Comment: @Tom I see. I think what you are looking for then can be found in the docs here (towards the bottom of that paragraph, just above related objects): https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#updating-multiple-objects-at-once... if this is what you are looking for, i'll update my answer

Comment: @James R That's what I was referencing: the example shows a way to increment an existing field, but it doesn't look like there's a way to dynamically change a field in bulk.